# Scrapy Filter duplicates extracted URLS from webpage

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, fwrite

OK, so i am using Scrapy. I am currently trying to scrape "snipplr.com/all/page" then extract urls in the page. I then filter the extracted URLs through reading a csv file the next time i run the spider to extract urls again. That was the plan, but somehow, i am getting a error of overridding results.

Process: Crawl webpage for links > check CSV file if already extracted in the past > If already, IgnoreRequest/dropItem else add to csv file

Spider Code:

```
import scrapy
import csv

from scrapycrawler.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "dmoz"
 allowed_domains = ["snipplr.com"]


def start_requests(self):
    #for i in xrange(1000):
    for i in range(2, 5):
        yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.snipplr.com/all/page/%d" % i)


def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ol/li/h3'):
        item = DmozItem()
        #item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a[last()]/@href').extract()
        #item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()

        reader = csv.reader(open('items.csv', 'w+')) #think it as a list
        for row in reader:
            if item['link'] == row:
                raise IgnoreRequest()

            else:
                f = open('items.csv', 'w')
                f.write(item[link'])
        yield item
```

However, i receive weird results like these which overide each other the next time i crawl a diffrent page but instead, i am looking to add the results to the file, not override

```
       clock/
/view/81327/chatting-swing-gui-tcp/
/view/82731/automate-system-setup/
/view/81215/rmi-factorial/
/view/81214/tcp-addition/
/view/81213/hex-octal-binary-calculator/
/view/81188/abstract-class-book-novel-magazine/
/view/81187/data-appending-to-file/
/view/81186/bouncing-ball-multithreading/
/view/81185/stringtokenizer/
/view/81184/prime-and-divisible-by-3/
/view/81183/packaging/
/view/81182/font-controller/
/view/81181/multithreaded-server-and-client/
/view/81180/simple-calculator/
/view/81179/inner-class-program/
/view/81114/cvv-dumps-paypals-egift-cards-tracks-wu-transfer-banklogins-/
/view/81038/magento-social-login/
/view/81037/faq-page-magento-extension/
/view/81036/slider-revolution-responsive-magento-extension/
/view/81025/bugfix-globalization/
```

There might be errors in the code, feel free to edit it to correct the code as needed.Thanks for providing help.

EDIT: Typos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually doing it in the wrong place, outputting crawled data should be done in the [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

Well, better use a normal database and filter duplicates with a database constraint, but anyway, if you still want to work with a `csv` file - create a pipeline that would first read the existing contents and remember it for future checks, for every item piped from the spider check if it is not seen before and write if not:

```
import csv

from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class CsvWriterPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            self.seen = set([row for row in f])

        self.file = open('items.csv', 'a+')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        link = item['link']

        if link in self.seen:
            raise DropItem('Duplicate link found %s' % link)

        self.file.write(link)
        self.seen.add(link)

        return item
```

Add it to [`ITEM_PIPELINES`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component) to turn it on:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline': 300
}
```

And your `parse()` callback would just yield an `Item`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ol/li/h3'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a[last()]/@href').extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks for your Alecxa, helped alot,  worked well, though i might as, what are the differences between pipeline and middleware, i am preetysure both can carry out the same functions with the same code ?

Comment: @CharlieC pipelines are for post-processing crawled items returned from the spiders - e.g. for storing items in the database. middlewares operate on request/response level. Hope that clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file just for writing from the beginning. for appending to the file you need to use `'a'` or `'a+'`.

Replace

```
f = open('items.csv', 'w')
```

with

```
f = open('items.csv', 'a')
```

Based on [BSD Library Functions Manual for fopen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/):

```
 The argument mode points to a string beginning with one of the following
 sequences (Additional characters may follow these sequences.):

 ``r''   Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.

 ``r+''  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.

 ``w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
         The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

 ``w+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
         the beginning of the file.

 ``a''   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.  The
         stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent writes
         to the file will always end up at the then current end of file,
         irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.

 ``a+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subse-
         quent writes to the file will always end up at the then current
         end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.
```